# No such column name sqlite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Am trying to add some values from a list to the android sqlite database but somehow it doesnt seem to find the table, and also the things i try to add in the table are not in the correct order according to logcat. I used 3 more tables and i added values into those with no problem. Ive been struggling on this for a while but i cant seem to see the problem. Any ideas?  Here is my code and error message:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
    currentCurrency = new ArrayList<String>();
    currentCurrencyDetails = new ArrayList<String>();
    currentCurrency.add("€");
    currentCurrencyDetails.add("€ EURO");
    currentCurrency.add("£");
    currentCurrencyDetails.add("£ UK POUND");
    currentCurrency.add("$");
    currentCurrencyDetails.add("$ USA DOLLAR");
    currentCurrency.add("¥");
    currentCurrencyDetails.add("¥ JAPAN YEN");

    db = new DBAdapter(this);
    db.open();
    for (int i = 0; i <= currentCurrency.size() - 1; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            db.insertDefaultCurrency(currentCurrency.get(i).toString(),
                    currentCurrencyDetails.get(i).toString(), 1);
        } else {
            db.insertDefaultCurrency(currentCurrency.get(i).toString(),
                    currentCurrencyDetails.get(i).toString(), 0);
        }
    }

}
```

DBAdapter class:

```
public static final String MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_TABLE = "MyCurrency";
public static final String MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY = "MyCurrentCurrency";
public static final String MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_NAMES = "MyCurrentCurrencyNames";
public static final String MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_BOOLEAN = "MyCurrentCurrencyBoolean";

private static final String DATABASE4_CREATE = "CREATE TABLE "
        + MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_TABLE + "(" + MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_NAMES + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_BOOLEAN + "INTEGER NOT NULL);";

    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE1_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE2_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE3_CREATE);
        db.execSQL(DATABASE4_CREATE);
    }

public long insertDefaultCurrency(String currency, String currencyDetails, int usedBoolean) {
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put(MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY, currency);
    initialValues.put(MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_NAMES, currencyDetails);
    initialValues.put(MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_BOOLEAN, usedBoolean);
    return db.insert(MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

logcat message:

```
01-28 10:31:26.865: E/SQLiteLog(8623): (1) table MyCurrency has no column named MyCurrentCurrencyBoolean
01-28 10:31:26.880: E/SQLiteDatabase(8623): Error inserting MyCurrentCurrencyBoolean=1 MyCurrentCurrency=€ MyCurrentCurrencyNames=€ EURO
01-28 10:31:26.880: E/SQLiteDatabase(8623): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table MyCurrency has no column named MyCurrentCurrencyBoolean (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO MyCurrency(MyCurrentCurrencyBoolean,MyCurrentCurrency,MyCurrentCurrencyNames) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change:

```
+ MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_BOOLEAN + "INTEGER NOT NULL);";
```

to

```
+ MY_CURRENT_CURRENCY_BOOLEAN + " INTEGER NOT NULL);";
```

The missing space between `"` and `INTEGER` is almost definitely the cause of your error. After that, clear your app's data and run it again so that the database is recreated.

Comment: indeed m8. thank you very much. Silly question but i really didnt see that

Comment: @antonislambrianides Please accept this answer as the solution by clicking the tick mark if it solved your problem.

Comment: i clicked it before but it said i need to wait a few minutes. After that i forgot:P done now